# What's the difference between raw pointer and weak_ptr?

Tags: c++, weak-ptr, raw-pointer

As in title. This question probably already has an answer but I failed to find one.

Comment: You can check if a weak_ptr points to something valid. You cannot do that with a raw pointer.

Comment: It is probably better if you look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) and see all the differences yourself. There is no one single difference, there are many.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The fundamental conceptual difference between a naked pointer and a `weak_ptr` is that if the object pointed to is destroyed, the naked pointer *won't* tell you about it. This is called a dangling pointer: a pointer to an object that doesn't exist. They're generally hard to track down.

The `weak_ptr` will. In order to use a `weak_ptr`, you must first convert it into a `shared_ptr`. And if that `shared_ptr` doesn't point to anything, then the object was deleted.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

std::weak_ptr<int> wp;

void test()
{
    auto spt = wp.lock(); // Has to be copied into a shared_ptr before usage
    if (spt) {
        std::cout << *spt << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "wp is expired\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    {
        auto sp = std::make_shared<int>(42);
        wp = sp;
        test();
    }
    test();
}
```

Output

```
42
wp is expired
```

Answer (score 23):

A raw pointer is (at least normally) simply an address. You can't tell anything about what it points *at* from the pointer itself.

A `weak_ptr` is always associated with a `shared_ptr`, so we probably need to start with a `shared_ptr` to make any sense of a `weak_ptr`.

A `shared_ptr` is reference counted, so it keeps track of how many references (pointers) to an object exist, and automatically destroys the object when no more references to that object exist.

As I already said, a `weak_ptr` is associated with a `shared_ptr`. Unlike a `shared_ptr`, the existence of a `weak_ptr` does *not* increment the reference count for the pointee object. To use a `weak_ptr`, you must first convert it to a `shared_ptr`. If the current reference count is positive, that will succeed, *and* converting the `weak_ptr` to a `shared_ptr` will increment the reference count to signify that the converted pointer is a "real" reference to the object. If, on the other hand, the reference count is already zero (meaning the pointee object has already been destroyed) the attempt to convert the `weak_ptr` to a `shared_ptr` will simply fail.

A `shared_ptr` means shared ownership of the pointee object. The pointee object will remain in existence as long as at least one shared_ptr to that object exists, *but* as soon as the last `shared_ptr` to the object is destroyed, so will the pointee object.

A `weak_ptr` means non-owning access to the pointee object. It allows access if the object exists. If the object has been destroyed, it tells you that the pointee object no longer exists rather than attempting to access the destroyed object.